# Changing User Password Data in MySQL (Laravel App)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I've set up my very first Laravel application on a VPS and I'm slowly getting to grips with the mysql command lines.

I'm trying to change the password data on a regular application member (user), not a root user for the database itself. Whilst it's stating changes have been made to a row, the password doesn't appear to be changing.

For the purposes of this issue, my database is called 'builders', here's what I have got so far;

```
mysql> USE builders;
       UPDATE users
    -> SET password='passwordgoeshere'
    -> WHERE id='1';

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0   

FLUSH PRIVILEGES: 
Query OK, 0 rows affected
```

I understand Laravel uses BCrypt (hash) for passwords so I generated a random one in order to see if that was the problem but it doesn't appear to be updating the password at all.

I'm most probably doing something very wrong, as I'm still learning any assistance on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use [Tinker](https://scotch.io/tutorials/tinker-with-the-data-in-your-laravel-apps-with-php-artisan-tinker) since you are using Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

- First, check the database which your `Laravel` application connects to.
- Second,  you should guarantee that the `passwordgoeshere` is a result of `bcrypt` function in `Laravel`

And it's a good idea to put your codes related on :)